# Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 - Angular2 - Spring API

Tags: json, spring, angular, spring-boot

My REST API which has been written in SpringBoot has following method for the purpose of uploading a photo.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/save-photo")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadPhoto(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file){

    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Attached file is empty");
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
        errorResponse.setMessage("Attached file is empty");
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    String returnPath = null;
    try {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        String saveDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmssSSS").format(new Date());
        Path path = Paths.get(UPLOAD_FOLDER + saveDate + "___"  + file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes); 
        returnPath = String.valueOf(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
        errorResponse.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> (errorResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    System.out.println("Before returning, return path = "+returnPath);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(returnPath, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Following is the code I have written to call the above method.

```
savePhoto(photoToSave: File) {

    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", photoToSave);

    let savedPath = this._http
        .post(this._endpointUrl + "/save-photo", formData)
        .map(
        res => {
            return res.json();
        }
        )
        .catch(handleError);

    return savedPath;

}
```

File uploading process is fine. But Angular2 gives me the following error.

> Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0

Note that the F is the starting letter of the path the server returns.

Why this happens? I think the server response is not a JSON. But why? Usually RestControllers return JSON. All other controller methods in my server works fine. 
How to resolve this?

Response Captured from Browser console

Header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Content-Length:88
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 26 May 2017 04:33:05 GMT
Vary:Origin
```

Response:

```
F:\Work\Images\170526100305388___2.jpg
```

**EDIT**

Screen shots from the brwoser
[image]

Response:

[image]

Comment: Use developer tools' network tab to see what response you are getting and maybe change your `res.json()` according to that. If you just want to return json from your back-end, the question isn't related with angular

Comment: Then just return the response. Why do you want to convert it to a json?

Comment: Thanks. It fixed the issue. But I had to return `res.url`. May I know why? Because according to the browser, the response is just the string path.

Comment: So if you just do `return res;` it prints an object with a `url` key?

Comment: Sorry for that. Infact what url refers to is the url of the endpoint. This is what it prints when I return res. `Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/tender/save-new/save-photo`

Comment: So what should it be printing?

Comment: `F:\Work\Images\170526100305388___2.jpg` the path to the location to which the photo was saved.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot with a response from your network tab?

Comment: added the screenshots

Comment: Shouldn't `return res` give you directly this value? How do you use `savePhoto` inside your component

Comment: I just console.log it. it gives me following. `Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/tender/save-new/save-photo`. Even the service prints the same

Comment: I used a work around. I returned a json object from the server and accessed it successfully using Angular. I do not know why this happened. In the same application, I have returned a int and used it in angular.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :-) you can self-answer or delete the question if you like :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as a answer the workaround I used to get over the issue. Hope it might help somebody.

What I did was instead of returning a String ResponseEntity, I created a JSON object which encapsulates the string I want to return and returned as the response.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("savedPath", returnPath);

return new ResponseEntity<>(obj, HttpStatus.OK);
```

In the front end, I just return the `response.json()`

```
let savedPath = this._http
    .post(this._endpointUrl + "tender/save-new/save-photo", formData)
    .map(
    res => {
        return res.json();
    }
    )
    .catch(handleError);
```

Now in the controller class, I can access the saved path in following way.

```
this._tendersService.savePhoto(files[0])
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("saved path = " + res.savedPath);
    }

    );
```

Comment: and I am not marking this as the correct/accepted answer since this does not resolve my initial issue. This is just an another way of getting it done

Comment: it looks like you did accept your own answer after all :P